# How do I change the number of columns in a matrix into n, so that every nth row is moved to the new column?

Tags: r, matrix

So this probably a very newbie question, but let's say I have this matrix

```
mat <- matrix(rep(c(1,2),3),nrow=6)

     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    1
[4,]    2
[5,]    1
[6,]    2
```

If I change to the number of columns to 2, the order I get is

```
matrix(mat,ncol=2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    1
[3,]    1    2
```

But I want it to be

```
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    2
```

I understand that n=col basically splits the matrix in half, and then moves the lower half to the new column. Is there a way to tell R to do in the specific way that I want?

Comment: There is `byrow` argument in `matrix`, `matrix(mat,ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `byrow = TRUE`, R will assign the elements of the matrix along rows first, giving you what you want:

```
matrix(mat, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    2
```

Comment: Oh Jesus. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
cbind(mat[c(TRUE, FALSE),], mat[c(FALSE, TRUE),])
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    1    2
#[3,]    1    2
```